# Does it make sense to split the user table into portfolio and user?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

The portfolio information will be used a lot to display the username and avatar image in comments. But it will also include some other public information.

Is there any advantage if I split the user table into the private and portfolio tables? Or should I just make one huge table which includes all the information such as password, profile_picture, etc?

It's probably not relevant but I am working with Laravel.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by private table, but portfolio definitively needs to have its own table. What do you mean by private? a table for storing the user's additional information like gender, age, profile picture and so on?

Comment: yes, i meant private data. So the private data would be: login, email, password and settings. 

The portfolio data would be: picture, public name, etc

Answer (score 1):

The typical best practice is to normalize to 2nd or 3rd normal form.

There is no major advantage in splitting out a few columns that are attributes of a user, assuming your tables will be InnoDB, as InnoDB has row level locking.  The things you want to move into a separate table are things that might have a date/time component to them like lastLoginDate, or repeating groups (question1/answer1).

Including these attributes, especially if they can be null cost you nothing with a varchar, if those columns are empty in a particular row.

Comment: thank you. If the portfolio consists of 30 columns. Would you consider this "a few columns". It sounds a lot to me, but I understand that databases are made to handle a lot.

Comment: That is a lot of columns and if I were to look at them all I might find some that are not normalized. It does not change the fact that if a small percentage of them are going to be used, there is essentially no overhead involved.